# Why cannot I access the method moveToHead outside DLinkedNode?

Tags: java, syntax, access-modifiers

```
public class LRUCache {

  public class DLinkedNode {
    int key;
    int value;
    DLinkedNode prev;
    DLinkedNode next;


  public void addNode(DLinkedNode node) {
    /**
     * Always add the new node right after head.
     */
    node.prev = head;
    node.next = head.next;

    head.next.prev = node;
    head.next = node;
  }

  public void removeNode(DLinkedNode node){
    /**
     * Remove an existing node from the linked list.
     */
    DLinkedNode prev = node.prev;
    DLinkedNode next = node.next;

    prev.next = next;
    next.prev = prev;
  }

  public void moveToHead(DLinkedNode node){
    /**
     * Move certain node in between to the head.
     */
    removeNode(node);
    addNode(node);
  }

  public DLinkedNode popTail() {
    /**
     * Pop the current tail.
     */
    DLinkedNode res = tail.prev;
    removeNode(res);
    return res;
  }
  }

  private Map<Integer, DLinkedNode> cache = new HashMap<>();
  private int size;
  private int capacity;
  private DLinkedNode head, tail;

  public LRUCache(int capacity) {
    this.size = 0;
    this.capacity = capacity;

    head = new DLinkedNode();
    // head.prev = null;

    tail = new DLinkedNode();
    // tail.next = null;

    head.next = tail;
    tail.prev = head;
  }

  public int get(int key) {
    DLinkedNode node = cache.get(key);
    if (node == null) return -1;

    // move the accessed node to the head;
    moveToHead(node);

    return node.value;
  }

  public void put(int key, int value) {
    DLinkedNode node = cache.get(key);

    if(node == null) {
      DLinkedNode newNode = new DLinkedNode();
      newNode.key = key;
      newNode.value = value;

      cache.put(key, newNode);
      addNode(newNode);

      ++size;

      if(size > capacity) {
        // pop the tail
        DLinkedNode tail = popTail();
        cache.remove(tail.key);
        --size;
      }
    } else {
      // update the value.
      node.value = value;
      moveToHead(node);
    }
  }
}
```

I was working on a leetcode problem and decided to take a look at the solution. In the solution, the methods for DLinkedNode are defined outside the class as private methods. This was something that I had not seen before. So I wanted to see if the code would work if I moved the methods inside the class and declared them public along with the class. It did not work. I would love to know why.

I am trying to understand access modifiers in Java. I have made the DLinkedNode class public and also every method defined within it. I do not get why moveToHead is not accessible outside its own class.

Comment: How are you trying to invoke it?   They are accessible, but you do need an instance of DLinkedNode to invoke them on.

Comment: I see. Why were they accessible before without an instance? Is it because earlier they were defined outside DLinkedNode?

Comment: A method defined in a class is an instance method and operates on an instance of that class.  You invoke it by doing instance.method().  If you don't want it to be an instance method, use the static modifier.